# Realtime changing values with formulas for input type jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to inputs:

- First where the user can type amount (for example 1000).
- The second input is readonly. 
  I need to make the value in the second input from the value of First+1% (percent).

So if the user type value in the first field: 1000.
In the Second field must appear 1010

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#summWithoutComission").keyup(function() {
    var thisVal = $("#summWithoutComission").val;
    $("#summWithComission").val(thisVal);
  });
});
```

Markup:

```
<input type="text" id="summWithoutComission" name="AMOUNT" maxlength="50" value="1000" class="text-field" />
<input type="text" id="summWithComission" value="" readonly class="text-field" />
```

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9hpyg1pc/4/

Comment: First use `var thisVal=$("#summWithoutComission").val();` instead of `var thisVal=$("#summWithoutComission").val;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a percentage to a number you should multiply that number by 1 plus the percentage fraction.

A percentage fraction is the fraction divided by 100.  For your example 1 divided by 100 or 1/100 = 0.01, then add 1 to this percentage fraction so you get 1.01

Using 3490 entry for example 3490+1% = 3490 * 1.01 = 3524.9

Thus for your example it would be:

1000 + 1% = 1000 * 1.01 = 1010

Now to adjust your code:  We need to parse it to a numeric value first.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#summWithoutComission").keyup(function() {
    var thisVal = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var percentValue = thisVal * 1.01;
    $("#summWithComission").val(percentValue );
  });
});
```

Now, notice that you have a value already in the first field.  SO to get that to calculate you can simply trigger your keyup like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#summWithoutComission").keyup(function() {
    var thisVal = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var percentValue = thisVal * 1.01;
    $("#summWithComission").val(percentValue );
  }).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Here is an updated fiddle with that in place: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/9hpyg1pc/7/

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle example you need to add jquery as an external js resource:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js
```

But this should resolve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#summWithoutComission").keyup(function(){

             var thisVal=$("#summWithoutComission").val();
             var commVal = (parseFloat(thisVal) * (1/100)) + parseFloat(thisVal);
             $("#summWithComission").val(commVal);

        });
    });
```

Comment: maybe use `var thisVal= parseFloat($("#summWithoutComission").val());` to avoid parse twice in the next line.